# Rodapé no fim da página e depois do conteúdo

Tags: css, html5

Tenho um rodapé que fica fixo logo após algum conteúdo pequeno 'meio da tela' e não no fim da página, eu uso `sidebar`.

Gostaria que ele ficasse no fim da página quando não houver conteúdo, e no fim quando o conteúdo for grande que tenha barra de rolagem.

```css
CSS:
#footer {
  position: relative;
  clear: left;
  background: #7386D5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 5%;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
rodape.php:
<div id="footer">
  <label id="label">Copyright © Site name, 20XX</label>
</div>
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Sistema de Avaliação - SAV</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style4.css">
        <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar  -->
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <h3>Sistema de Avaliação - SAV</h3>
                    <strong>SAV</strong>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                    <?php
                    include './menuCadastro.php';
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="avaliacao.php">
                            <i></i>
                            Avaliação
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="relatorios.php">
                            <i></i>
                            Relatórios
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="alterarSenha.php">
                            <i></i>
                            Alterar Senha
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    include './menuParametro.php';
                    ?>
                </ul>

                <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="logoff.php" class="article"> Sair</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- Page Content  -->
            <div id="content">
            Conteúdo
            <?php
            require './rodape.php';
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: crie três segmentos no seu template `header` que também pode ser `hero` caso não queira um header, `main` e `footer`, no `main` insira uma classe css que contenha um calculo de VH subtraindo o `hero` ou `header` somando ao `footer` em uma propriedade `min-height`: exemplo `.main-fluent min-height calc((64px + 256px) - 100vh)` onde neste exemplo o hader tem 64px e o footer tem 256px

Comment: Não entendi direito, eu uso side bar.

Comment: Cade seu código? Como que vc quer que a gente te responda se vc só colocou uma div e diz que tem sidebar? Coloca ai o mínimo de código e contexto pra alguém poder te responder

Comment: @Ari não entendi, como assim sidebar?

Comment: @Ari de uma olhada neste link https://codepen.io/flourigh/pen/gObMxzz é um micro view do que mencionei

Comment: Não funciona pra mim, quando coloco o conteúdo ele fica fixo e não no fim do conteúdo.  position: fixed;
    clear: left;
    background: #7386D5;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 3.5%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;

Comment: @Ari deu uma olhada no link?

Comment: Olhei sim, coloquei no meu e ficou fixo.

Comment: nem tem parametro fixed no meu exemplo, se você deixou no seu, remova

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar

```
#footer{

width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;

}
```

Ao invés de usar o **position: relative** use o **fixed**

Comment: Nesse trecho de CSS não vai resolver o que ele quer como diz ele "**e no fim quando o conteúdo for grande que tenha barra de rolagem**" se for colocado algum conteúdo que faça com que a página tenha barras de rolagem o rodapé vai estar sempre ali fixo e ele não quer isso.

Comment: Verdade @leandro, ele fica fixo no fim da pagina, se tiver rolagem ele permanece fixo.